# What should I use for a default value for a json column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Background: I have been tasked with grafting some simple key/value data pairs to an existing database table in SQL Server (in Azure). The nature of the KvP data is simply some extended data that may or may not exist for all rows.

Further, the data is somewhat *freeform* as not all rows will have the same key/value pairs. This is very much *bolt-on-data* that (in my opinion) doesn't merit the complexity of a related table. Instead, I've decided to try using JSON to hold the data and so, to get my feet wet I've tried the following:

First, I created a new column on my table thusly:

```
ALTER TABLE [TheTable] 
    ADD [ExtendedData] NVARCHAR(512) NOT NULL DEFAULT('')
```

Second, I picked a few records at random and added some additional JSON in the newly created column, for example:

```
{ "Color":"Red", "Size":"Big", "Shape":"Round" }
```

Finally, I expected to be able to query this extra data, by using the JSON_VALUE function in SQL, like this:

```
SELECT 
    Field1,
    Field2,
    JSON_VALUE(ExtendedData, '$.Color') AS Color,
    JSON_VALUE(ExtendedData, '$.Size') AS Size
FROM
    MyTable
```

I expected my output to be a result set with 4 columns (Field1, Field2, Color, Size) where some (most) of the Color and Size fields were NULL (because the majority of rows simply do not have any json data) - but instead I got an error complaining

> JSON text is not properly formatted

This led me to suspect that ALL of my `ExtendedData` should be properly formatted JSON for my new query to work, and so replacing my default column value of '' (an empty string) with '{}' seemingly fixes my problem.

But I am left wondering if this is the correct solution.  Should I indeed default my new `ExtendedData` column to use an empty json object '{}', or is it safe to use an empty string '' and I am missing something syntactically in my query?

Comment: Leaving the column null should work

Comment: Interesting, I didn't try leaving the column null because when these tables were created a decision was made to disallow nulls (ie. everything is NOT NULL).  So following that pattern, I tried to give the new column a default value to back-fill existing rows.

Comment: Well, if you have to put in a default value, what would the default color and size be? Create a json snippet that basically has what you need { "Color" : "red", ...

Comment: That would be exactly right, except the data is non-standard (which is why I decided to use something squishy like json).  Some rows might have a color, some rows might have a size, some might have a name, or a height, or a refractionindex, etc.  There is no rhyme or reason to _what_ might get tacked on a given row - but I do have _some_ queries that go looking for certain more common things, like (for example) 'size'.  Thats why an empty json string seems to work so well, '{}' is like an empty KvP collection.

Comment: null values won't cause such an issue. You can check the existence invalid JSONs by `select * from TheTable  WHERE ISJSON(ExtendedData) = 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any evidence to the contrary, and working within the rules established for this database, I've decided to use a default value of '{}' for my JSON data.

If anyone else does this, be careful as some API's / parsers / IDE's might not like the string '{}' and require you to escape the sequence as '{{}}'.